# How to correctly install nvidia graphic driver on ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I have been struggling to install the correct driver for my GTX 1080ti on my ubuntu. I have tried to install from various method (GUI or terminal) and many driver version from 390 to 430 but it seems that after reboot, the display is always a mess (ubuntu booting logo and folder gets bigger, one of my monitor get black screen, screen is lagging, and constant warning "encounter problem") and when I check the system details it change from NV132 to pipeline something which isn't GTX 1080ti. Would anyone help me with this? I already reinstall ubuntu countless times already. Forgot to mention I use dual boot with windows 10 on this machine. And the windows part is working fine